# Java IllegalAccessError

Tags: java

Even though my classes are public I cant access them. Here are my classes:

Student Class:

```
public class Student {
    String name="xdxd";
    int studentNo;
    String classes;
    String course1;
    String course2;
    String course3;
    double stuAvg;
    boolean isPassed;
    void getStudtName(){
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student stud1= new Student();
        stud1.getStudtName();
    }
}
```

The same code works in IntellijIdea, but when I create those files in a directory and run cmd there ( they are on the same folder 100% and I run the cmd there) I get an error saying :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class main tried to access method 'void Student.getStudtName()' (main is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @5a4041cc; Student is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at main.main(main.java:4)
```

Could you guys point me what am I doing wrong?

I was expecting it to work as usual just as IntellijIdea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `public` `getStudtName` method.
`public void getStudtName()`